# HTML selected="selected" not working initially

Tags: php, html, laravel-4

So I have this select box that contains a list of position inside a person's profile. Upon opening the page, it should display the selected position of that specific person. However, it is not working for the first time, but when I change the position and save it, it will now display the selected position. I need it to work without doing that.

Here is my code:

```
   <select name="position" id="position" class="form-control">
       <option></option>
       <?php
       $post = DB::table('ccl_position')->orderBy('position_name', 'asc')->get();
       foreach ($post as $pos)
       {
       ?>
       <option<?=($pos->ccl_position_id==$crew->position ? ' selected="selected"' : '')?> value="<?=$pos->ccl_position_id?>"><?=$pos->position_name?></option>
       <?php } ?>
   </select>
```

The "$crew->position" is where the selected position of the said person.

[here is what it looks like when opening the profile for the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgZQk.png)

[after I changed the position and update it. it will now display the selected position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz5o3.png)

Comment: Why do you expect something different in the first instance? If none of the items were previously marked selected, the first option will be the default, which is empty.

Comment: Please init an example data for `$post` and `$crew`. Nobody know what you initialized in it.

Comment: solved it guys. instead of pulling the data directly from the query, I passed it to another variable and put that variable in the condition inside the select box options. And that seems to solve the problem.